# Bot de discord no encuentra el comando (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found
```

Me sale ese error y no estaría pudiendo solucionarlo; si alguien me puede ayudar.

Es para un bot de música para el ds con mis amigos pero no estaría andando.

Si alguien es capaz de ayudarme a resolver el problema.

dejo el link a GitHub porque no me deja si pongo el código acá
pd: si alguien le es útil, úselo sabiendo que tiene que ser para uso personal.

https://github.com/GastonLossio/Discord_bot.git

Comment: Por favor lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita la pregunta proveyendo un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].La descripción de tu problema está bien, pero debieras incluir la parte relevante del código que estás utilizando en la pregunta. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderla y los links a repositorios o recursos externos no son válidos, pues mañana podrían estar rotos. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: La función setup en el programa principal no se ejecuta. Por lo tanto, no se agregan los cogs.